# PostgreSQL ERROR: subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I'm having an inordinate amount of trouble using CTEs as arguments to a PostgreSQL function call, and no amount of refactoring into subqueries seems to help; I get either `subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level` or `function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level`.  The simplified SQL:

```
create type similarity as (
  distance    float,
  explanation text
);

create or replace function similarity(my_user_id int)
returns table(user_id int, distance float, explanation hstore) as $$

  with factors as (
    select users.id as user_id, demographics.gender
    from users 
    join demographics on users.id = demographics.user_id),

  my_factors as (
    select user_id, gender
    from factors 
    where user_id = $1),

  similarities as (
    select factors.user_id, sim.distance, sim.explanation
    from factors, my_factors, similarity_gender(my_factors.gender, factors.gender) as sim)

  select user_id, distance, explanation from similarities;
$$ language sql stable strict;


create or replace function similarity_gender(my_gender text, other_gender text) returns similarity as $$
  declare
    distance  float;
    sim       similarity;
  begin
    if my_gender is null or other_gender is null then
      distance = 0.9;
    elsif (my_gender = other_gender) then
      distance = 0.0;
    else
      distance = 1.0;
    end if;

    sim.distance     = distance;
    sim.explanation  = hstore('gender', cast(sim.distance as text));
    return sim;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

Comment: BTW, it turns out that what I was trying to do is called LATERAL, and isn't in Postgres yet as of 9.1: http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2010/04/finding-our-way-to-lateral.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging, I created the test scenario:
<sub>You should have included that in your setup in the question.</sub>

```
-- drop schema x CASCADE;
create schema x
create table x.users(id int);
create table x.demographics (user_id int, gender text);

INSERT INTO x.users VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
INSERT INTO x.demographics VALUES (1, 'm'),(2, 'f'),(3, 'm'),(4, 'f'),(5, 'm');
```

This works now, after some fixes:

```
create type x.similarity as (
  distance    float,
  explanation text
);

create or replace function x.similarity_gender(my_gender text, other_gender text)
returns x.similarity as $$
  declare
    distance  float;
    sim       x.similarity;
  begin
    if my_gender is null or other_gender is null then
      distance = 0.9;
    elsif (my_gender = other_gender) then
      distance = 0.0;
    else
      distance = 1.0;
    end if;

    sim.distance     = distance;
    sim.explanation  = hstore('gender', cast(sim.distance as text));
    return sim;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql immutable;


create or replace function x.similarity(my_user_id int)
returns table(user_id int, distance float, explanation text) as $$

  with factors as (
    select u.id as user_id, d.gender
    from x.users u
    join x.demographics d on u.id = d.user_id),

  my_factors as (
    select f.user_id, f.gender
    from factors  f
    where f.user_id = $1),

  similarities as (
    select f.user_id, x.similarity_gender(m.gender, f.gender) AS sim
    from factors f, my_factors m)

  select s.user_id, (s.sim).distance, (s.sim).explanation
    from similarities s;
$$ language sql stable strict;
```

Call:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM x.similarity(2);
 user_id | distance |  explanation
---------+----------+---------------
       1 |        1 | "gender"=>"1"
       2 |        0 | "gender"=>"0"
       3 |        1 | "gender"=>"1"
       4 |        0 | "gender"=>"0"
       5 |        1 | "gender"=>"1"
```

#### Major points

- Create the function first, you have execution sequence reversed in your setup
- In function similarity you must qualify columns names to avoid name conflicts with OUT parameters of the same name (`user_id`, `distance`, `explanation`).
- Your CTE similarities was mangled. I pulled the function call similarity_gender(..) up into the SELECT list. In order not to call twice, I split it up in the next step.
- Use parenthesis to access the fields of composite types. Consult the [fine manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html#AEN7249).
- Return type of function similarity() had a bug: `explanation hstore`. Must be `explanation text`.

Comment: A million thanks - that works!  I would never have found the parens for composite types, despite re-reading that page several times today.  Likewise qualifying all the names.  We don't use schemas, but maybe I should here - this all gets called from Rails and I need to learn how schemas affect data compartmentalization. I'm still unclear on the last point; why can't I return an `hstore` from similarity? My eventual goal is to call a number of such similarity_ functions on different factors, average the numbers and concatenate the text explanation.

Comment: Cool. :) You *can* return an hstore from similarity(), but you *didn't*. Look at your SQL: you (try to) select the text field contained in the composite type.